# Como mostrar uma mensagem quando nenhum jradiobutton está selecionado?

Tags: java, netbeans

Estou fazendo um exercício em java swing que contem a seguinte tela com JRadioButtons:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando o "java swing" está selecionado ele deve mostrar uma mensagem ao clicar no JButton e vice versa com a segunda opção.
Porém como mostrar uma mensagem quando não houver nenhuma opção selecionada?

```
    private void clickEvento(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                             

    if (jrbJavaSwing.isSelected()) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Java Swing");
    }
    if (jrbOutraLP.isSelected()) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Outra linguagem... Tem certeza?");
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Você não selecionou nada");
```

Pois dessa forma com este JOptionPane na última linha, ele fica retornando a mensagem sempre.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

O método `isSelected` retorna um *boolean*, ele retorna `false` caso não esteja selecionado, então:

```java
private void clickEvento(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                             

    if (jrbJavaSwing.isSelected()) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Java Swing");
    }
    if (jrbOutraLP.isSelected()) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Outra linguagem... Tem certeza?");
    }
    if (jrbJavaSwing.isSelected() == false && jrbOutraLP.isSelected() == false) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Você não selecionou nada");
    }
}
```